# SED Errors when building asciidoc

Tags: asciidoc

I get the following two warnings/errors when building [asciidoc](http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/):

```
$./configure --prefix=/home/my_installations/
./configure: line 1233: AC_PROG_SED: command not found
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
```

and then also with make:

```
$ make
Fixing CONF_DIR in asciidoc.py
/bin/sh: line 2: @SED@: command not found
Fixing CONF_DIR in a2x.py
/bin/sh: line 2: @SED@: command not found
```

This is with the latest stable versions of automake and autoconf on the moment of this writing:

- automake 1.13
- autoconf 2.69

Any thoughts on what this means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you run `autoconf` before `./configure`?

Comment: I can't believe that I missed that. Running autoconf first fixed it. Thanks!